# Sine/Cosine Subtraction Formulas

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

The differential equation $\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}+ \omega^2 y=0$ has the general solution $y = A\cos (\omega t)+ B\sin (\omega t)$. Also given are the initial values: $y(a) = A, y'(a) = B$.

I tried:

$$y(a) = A\cos(\omega a) + B\sin(\omega a )= A$$

$$y'(a) = −\omega A\sin(\omega a) + \omega B\cos(\omega a)= B$$

And then substituted $A$ and $B$ into the general solution:

$$y = (A\cos(\omega a) + B\sin(\omega a))\cosωt + \omega (−A\sin(\omega a) + B\cos(\omega a))\sin(\omega t)$$

From here I can't get it to work. I want to simplify and express y with the subtraction formulas. 
The answer is $y = A\cos(\omega (t−a)) + \frac{B}{\omega}\sin(\omega (t−a))$

I know how the formulas work, But I can't figure out how $\frac{B}{\omega}$ got there.
Please help, I'm stuck.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Well, there’s an $\omega$ in the term that involves $B$ in $y'$, so...

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. But what happened to Cesareo's post?. Why was it downvoted and deleted?

Answer (score 1):

It is unfortunate that you used the letters $A$ and $B$ for two different sets of variables, first for the undetermined coefficients in the solution and then for the prescribed initial values.

If you remove the second use, you get
\begin{align}
y(a)&=A\cos(ωa)+B\sin(ωa),\\
\frac{y'(a)}{ω}&=−A\sin(ωa)+B\cos(ωa).
\end{align}
The right side is a rotation of the vector $\pmatrix{A\\B}$ by the angle $ωa$, so you can reverse it by a rotation by $-ωa$,
\begin{align}
A&=y(a)\cos(ωa)-\frac{y'(a)}{ω}\sin(ωa),\\
B&=y(a)\sin(ωa)+\frac{y'(a)}{ω}\cos(ωa).
\end{align}
Inserting that should lead directly to the trigonometric subtraction formulas.

---

As the differential equation is homogeneous, the family of the solutions is invariant under time shifts. Thus you could have from the start used
$$
y(x)=A\cos(ω(x-a))+B\sin(ω(x-a)),
$$
as the form of the general solution. Then it would follow immediatly that $y(a)=A$ and $y'(a)=ωB$.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to apply a time shift by $a$, so that the initial conditions simplify to

$$y(0)=A\cos(0)+B\sin(0),\\y'(0)=-A\omega\sin(0)+B\omega\cos(0).$$

The rest is trivial.